# R programme, to create a new dataframe to remove some columns and rows

Tags: r

With the dataset swiss:

1. I want to create a data frame of only the rows 10,11,13 and only variables Examination, Education and Infant.Mortality.
2. To Create a new variable that will be the proportion of Examination (Examination / Total)

i know how to get/create say FIRST/LAST 3 or 5 0r  even 100 but not variables of either columns or rows

```
i.e   swiss[nrows(swiss)-4:nrows,]

columns:  colnames(swiss)
[1] "Fertility"        "Agriculture"     
[3] "Examination"      "Education"       
[5] "Catholic"         "Infant.Mortality".... here i want only for examination  education & infant
```

Comment: swiss[c(10,11,13), c("Examination", "Education","Infant.Mortality")]

Answer (score 0):

You can call on rows explicitly using the row numbers inside the c() function

```
library(dplyr)
df_new <- df %>% select(Examination, Education, Infant) %>% mutate(new_var = Examination / Total)

df_new <- df_new[c(10,11,13),]
```

your other option is using base R:

```
df_new <- df[c(10,11,13),c("Examination", "Education", "Infant")]
df_new$new_var <- df_new$Examination / df_new$Total***
```

*** you would have to define what total is